# jQuery code, how I can do easier to read

Tags: jquery, code-readability

I wanna try to make my code easier to read and I'm looking for a solution something like this, in Visual Basic:

```
 With $('.class or sector') {
    $(this).removeClass('some-class');
    $(this).addClass('some-other-class');
 } End With
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.class or sector') = function() {
    $('.class or sector inside > *', this).addClass('some-class');
}
```

`.container` is a class inside `.footer-finale` 
maybe anyone can help me

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where is your HTML code?

Comment: I wanna try to make my code easier to read...  html code isn't important.
i don't wanna always write...
$('.footer-finale .container')...
$('.footer-finale span > a')...
or anything like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery uses a fluent interface, so you can chain your calls.

```
$('.class')
    .removeClass('some-class')
    .addClass('some-other-class');
```

You can also assign a variable:

```
var item = $('.class');
item.removeClass('some-class');
item.addClass('some-other-class');
```

Comment: Thanks... that's i'm looking for